# Multiple cells propagating information into single master cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with 4 "sub-sheets" and 1 master sheet. Within the sub-sheets I have a column for notes. Each note corresponds to a task in a row. These tasks are identical throughout all 4 sub-sheets and the master sheet, the only difference will be the information within the notes. I want the notes from each sub-sheet to propagate in the relevant cell within the master sheet. There may be a completely obvious solution and perhaps it's due to today being a Friday before a long weekend, but I can't figure out a way to do this in the master sheet with references to multiple sheets. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use a formula to concatenate the notes from the 4 sub sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your master sheet is named "Sheet1", and your "sub-sheets" are named "Sheet2" through "Sheet5", and your notes are in column D.

To get the notes from the sub-sheets on row one into the master sheet, use this formula in cell D1 on the master sheet:

```
=Sheet2!D1 & Sheet3!D1 & Sheet4!D1 & Sheet5!D1
```

Comment: That worked! I've never used "&" before, that's very useful!